# Push footer after dynamic table to last print page

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I'm trying to make an invoice where the total price is displayed on the bottom of the last printed page.

Any ideas?

I tried to set the footer `static` or `absolute` and `bottom: 0px;` but this didn't work.

```css
@media print {
  body {
    position: relative;
  }
  #invoice_footer {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
  #invoice_content:after {
    display: block;
  }
  #invoice_content {
    page-break-after: auto;
  }
  #producttable {
    page-break-inside: auto !important;
  }
  .product {
    page-break-before: auto !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div id="invoice_content">
      /* DYNAMIC TABLE */
    </div>

    <div id="invoice_footer">
      /* total price and extra info */
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `<div> id="invoice_footer">` - is this actually in your code, or just a mistake when posting to Stack Overflow?

Comment: Mistake in stack overflow, thanks for the remark

Comment: You might be able to do something with this: https://jsfiddle.net/3hy42tuq/

Comment: Or maybe this: https://jsfiddle.net/3hy42tuq/1/

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the table height because it's a dynamic table. So I can't input a table height I think.

Comment: This might work then. I don't know how it will behave on page breaks.
https://jsfiddle.net/3hy42tuq/2/

Comment: I will give it a try! thanks